# Rename item in a listview c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, rename

i would like to know how can i change the name of a ListView item in the traditional select>F2>edit>enter manner. How can i open that little editable textbox just over the item?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the LabelEdit property to true.  Add a KeyDown event handler to recognize the F2 keystroke.  Like this:

```
    private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.F2 && listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].BeginEdit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i also use the AfterLabelEdit event to do some logic after the edition, :)

Comment: Is this for ListBox? It sounds like for ListView!

Comment: Sure, ListBox doesn't support editing.  Next time downvote the question instead of the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is to use a ListView, which has this feature built-in.
Set the [`LabelEdit` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.labeledit.aspx) to true.

Answer (score 2):

ListBox doesn't have any property of the item selected which can be used to update the text.  It is an object or any type, not a simple text.  As SLaks mentioned, you can present ListView like a ListBox and use LabelEdit event to modify the text of selected Item.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.F2 && listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
       listView1.LabelEdit = true; 
       listView1.SelectedItems[0].BeginEdit();
    }
}
```